# Refresh CGridView by passing parameter(LinkID) in Yii Framework

Tags: yii

I am trying to refresh/update `CGridView` by passing parameter `linkid` to grid while performing `AjaxSubmitButton`. How to achieve this ?

My `AjaxSubmitbutton` code:

```
<?php  
    echo CHTML::ajaxSubmitButton('Save', Yii::app()->createUrl('baseContact/NewEditStructure',array("id" => $base)),
     array('success' => 'function(){
         changeEdittab();
         $.fn.yiiGridView.update("editstructure-grid");
         $("#EditStructure-New").dialog("close"); return false;
     }'))
?>
```

Above code does not update grid based on `linkid`, I am new to YII how to pass `linkid` to update `CgridView` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add js: before js function in your code.

```
echo CHTML::ajaxSubmitButton('Save', Yii::app()->createUrl('baseContact/NewEditStructure',array("id" => $base)),
       array('success' => 'js:function(){changeEdittab();
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("editstructure-grid");
      $("#EditStructure-New").dialog("close"); return false;}'))
```

Comment: id is CgridView ID which you have define.if your grid view id is "editstructure-grid" then you have pass correct.

Comment: How to pass ID to CGRidView update function ?   $.fn.yiiGridView.update("editstructure-grid");

Comment: your syntax is right.$.fn.yiiGridView.update("your_gridview_id");

Comment: I want to pass foreign key value to yiiCGridView.update

Comment: this is not a database key or id. it is html div id. you can not pass foreign key.

Comment: I want to filter grid based on header pk . Can you give me any idea to update Cgridview based on foreignkey ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44400/discussion-between-naveen-goyal-and-manadh)

Comment: i would like to pass sort parameter to `fn.yiiGridView.update`, is there an update to this?